# InfoPath Form losing content type - what is the cause?

Tags: infopath, forms-services, form-library

I have a form library in a SharePoint site collection with approximately 4000 browser enabled InfoPath forms residing in it at any given time. This form library also has approximately 160 content types enabled for use. Periodically there are forms which get submitted to the library that seem to 'lose' their content type. When this occurs, the form will use the default content type of the library. This causes problems when the user attempts to access the form after it has occurred. It also causes problems with workflows that are associated to specific properties of some content types.

I have a few questions:

1. Has anyone encountered this behavior from a form library before?
2. Does anyone have insight into what may be causing this behavior?

I suspect a timeout in InfoPath Form Services is occurring during the form submission but I am unable to find any indicators of this.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.